# how to "stabilize" a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div in the right side of the page and a header on top, e.g:

[image]

So i have the div of the menu and I wrapped it in another div, setting it to float to the right, additionally, before the menu div i have the header div on top.
What I'm trying to do is make another 2 sections one of them should be an iFrame (don't shoot me please),

whenever I try to add other divs, either the menu is getting on top of them or they just placed underneath the end of the menu.
I want it to be like that:
[image]

this is a part of the code:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Pre-Test</h1>
</div>


<div id="wrap" style="right: 0;height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
       <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
       <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
     ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="two_main_frames">
    <div class="main_right_frame">
        <iframe src="http://www.amazon.com">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.two_main_frames {
    direction: rtl;
    width: 80%;
    /*height: 100%;*/

}

.main_right_frame {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
    direction: rtl;
    clear: both;
}
```

You can check out the code over here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xQgSm/124/

p.s: I don't know if it has anything to do with this but when i open it in mp phone it shows pretty messed up. is there any way to fix that too?
thanks.

Comment: A. Where is the failing part? (Your code fragment & fiddle only have the working part). B. Can you create a MINIMAL example in the fiddle (It's too much pointless code that distracts)? C. If you're using CSS, why do you inline styles (again, pointless and distracts)?

Comment: edited it according to your guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

For the messed up mobile display it's b/c you haven't coded your site to be [responsive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). Simply, using a CSS framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/) will take care of that for you.

Comment: Thanks. First, I need to keep the java part in order to maintain the menu style. Second, I did what you said and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure? When using bootstrap (I recommend using it since its arguably the most popular) you have to use the classes that it predefines for you, so you would have to tack those css classes on to your existing elements. BTW what do you mean by "java part"?

Comment: I meant javaScript, and I don't use bootstrap at the moment.

Comment: the menu was on top of the 'iframe' div.

Comment: My answer is directed towards the responsive design issue for mobile. I don't see how it would cause layout issues unless you are using the framework incorrectly. Like I said you should use bootstrap, its fairly simple and it has a large community.

Answer (score 0):

following CSS rules floating element should come first in DOM tree:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="iframe"></div>
    <div class="anything-else"></div>
</div>
```

Doesn't matter if You want menu to flot left or right. For Your layout this would be something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1son5fyg/):

HTML:

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="menu">Menu</div>
    <div class="iframe">Iframe</div>
    <div class="anything-else">All the rest content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.content {
    overflow: auto;
}

.menu {
    float: right;
    background: lime;
    width: 33vw;
    height: 300px;
}

.iframe {
    float: right;
    background: red;
    width: 33vw;
    height: 300px;
}

.anything-else {
    float: none; /* we dont want to float last div */
    background: lightblue;
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
}
```

No JavaScript tag required :)